# d3js zoom into plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

I have made a plot with d3js and because the plot function goes outside the plot I wanted to clip it. At the same time I also thought about zooming. Therefor I started implementing the following example into my code; http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892919

Unfortunately however, it seems that my implementation is incorrect. My x- and y-axis labels seem to disappear + the background has turned black + the actual plot is missing until you try to zoom :S.

Solution how to fix, i.e., correctly implement this is asked. Further I am also open for improvements of my code.

Jsfiddle of the version with zoom: http://jsfiddle.net/n3Lndkum/12/
Jsfiddle of the last working version: http://jsfiddle.net/n3Lndkum/9/

Embedded version:

```js
var margin  = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 50},
    width   = 250 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height  = 250 - margin.top  - margin.bottom,
    padding = 50;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([0, 10]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0, 10]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5)
 .innerTickSize(-6)
 .outerTickSize(0)
 .tickPadding(7);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5)
 .innerTickSize(-6)
 .outerTickSize(0)
 .tickPadding(7);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .scaleExtent([0.1, 32])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var data = [];

for (var k = -100; k < 101; k++) {
    data.push({x: k/10, y: 0.5*k*k/100});
}

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .interpolate("linear");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",  width  + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top  + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// Add x axis
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class","x axis")
 .attr("transform","translate(0," + height + ")")
 .call(xAxis);

// Add y axis 
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class","y axis")
 .call(yAxis);

/* append additional X axis */
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + [0, 0] + ")")
 .call(xAxis.innerTickSize(6).tickPadding(-20).tickFormat(""));

/* append additional y axis */
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class","y axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + [width, 0] + ")")
 .call(yAxis.innerTickSize(6).tickPadding(-20).tickFormat(""));

// Add x axis label  
svg.append("text")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
 .style("font-size","15")
 .style("text-anchor", "middle")
 .text("x axis");

// Add y axis label
svg.append("text")
 .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
 .attr("y",0 - margin.left)
 .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
 .attr("dy", "1em")
 .style("font-size","15")
 .style("text-anchor", "middle")
 .text("y axis");

// Add x grid
svg.append("g")         
 .attr("class","grid")
 .attr("transform","translate(0," + height + ")")
 .call(xAxis
        .tickSize(-height,-height,0)
  .tickFormat("")
        );

// Add y grid
svg.append("g")         
 .attr("class","grid")
 .call(yAxis
  .tickSize(-width,-width,0)
  .tickFormat("")
 );

function zoomed() {
 svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
   svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    
    // Add data
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class","line")
        .attr("d",line(data));
    
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.grid path {
    stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wait, do you want to pan by changing the range of the xy, or do you want to do a zoom out like increments of what would be 2 be 4 then 6 etc. ? Also is it intentional for the random path to appear on a mouse down?

Comment: Both pan and zoom, and indeed with increments. I covered that part by using ".scaleExtent([0.1, 32])" if I am correct. Furthermore if possible I only want to pan until the graph is at the border of the plot, so you cannot pan further then the data goes. The "random" path is the plot x^2. My logic told me that because you zoom in the plot is to be redrawn everytime, therefor I put that part in the zoomed function.

Comment: I sort of get what you're saying. But with out a doubt if you pan or zoom the graph needs to be redraw, so with each redraw you also redraw the path.

Answer (score 2):

Few things here:

1.) You aren't applying a clip-path to the line.  This is why it overruns the grid.

2.) Your grid is black because you've appended a `rect` to it (so it can receive the pan/zoom mouse events) but you aren't setting it's fill to something (it's black by default).  Note, you **can't** set it's fill to none since then it won't get the mouse events.

3.) You shouldn't share the axis definition like you are doing:

```
.call(xAxis.innerTickSize(6).tickPadding(-20).tickFormat(""));
```

The pan and zoom functionality is going to need to redraw the axis(es) and grid(s), keep a reference to each one you create.

4.) In your zoom event, don't re-append a new line.  Select the existing one and update it's data:

```
d3.select(".line")
  .attr("d", line(data));
```

Putting this all together:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Zoom + Pan</title>
<style>
  svg {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  
  rect {
    fill: transparent;
  }
  
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  
  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    clip-path: url(#clip);
  }
  
  .grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  
  .grid path {
    stroke-width: 0;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
      },
      width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 10])
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 10])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .x(x)
      .y(y)
      .scaleExtent([1, 32])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      .call(zoom);

    var xAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(5)
      .innerTickSize(-6)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .tickPadding(7);

    var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
      .innerTickSize(-6)
      .outerTickSize(0)
      .tickPadding(7);

    var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("top")
      .ticks(5)
      .innerTickSize(6)
      .tickPadding(-20)
      .tickFormat("");

    var yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
      .innerTickSize(6)
      .tickPadding(-20)
      .tickFormat("");

    var xGrid = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .tickSize(-height, -height, 0)
      .tickFormat("");

    var yGrid = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
      .tickSize(-width, -width, 0)
      .tickFormat("");
      
    // Add x grid
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x grid")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xGrid);

    // Add y grid
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y grid")
      .call(yGrid);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x1 axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis1);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y1 axis")
      .call(yAxis1);

    /* append additional X axis */
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x2 axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + [0, 0] + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

    /* append additional y axis */
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y2 axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + [width, 0] + ")")
      .call(yAxis2);

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);
      
    svg.append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    var data = [];

    for (var k = -100; k < 101; k++) {
      data.push({
        x: k / 10,
        y: 0.5 * k * k / 100
      });
    }

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.y);
      })
      .interpolate("linear");

    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line(data))

    function zoomed() {
      svg.select(".x1.axis").call(xAxis1);
      svg.select(".y1.axis").call(yAxis1);
      svg.select(".x2.axis").call(xAxis2);
      svg.select(".y2.axis").call(yAxis2);
      svg.select(".x.grid").call(xGrid);
      svg.select(".y.grid").call(yGrid);

      d3.select(".line")
        .attr("d", line(data));
    }
  </script>
```